# How can I modify this function to use multiple tabs and columns for each tab?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using this function to copy down columns.

```
function copyDown4() {

var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var tabs = ['Imported'];
  var columns = [9];
  if(tabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName()) !== -1){
  var cell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
    if(columns.indexOf(col) !== -1){
      if(cell.getFormula() !== ""){
    var destination = activeSheet.getRange(2, col, activeSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
        cell.copyTo(destination)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I modify it so, rather than creating multiple copies of this function, I can include multiple tabs each with their own specific column numbers?

I assume I can add more tabs simply with this

```
var tabs = ['Imported','Another','And Another'];
  var columns = [9];
```

But I'm not sure about the columns. Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: In your current script, it seems that the value of the active cell is copied to from the row 2 to last row for the column at the active cell. You want to run this script at the several sheets and several columns by modifying the script. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, for example, how about modifying `var tabs = ['Imported','Another','And Another'];` and `var columns = [9, 10, 11];`? In this modification, the sheet can be selected by `if(tabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName()) !== -1)`, and the column can be selected by `if(columns.indexOf(col) !== -1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include multiple tabs each with their own specific column numbers, you can create a dictionary.

```js
function copyDown4() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var tabs = {
    'Imported': [9],
    'Another': [10, 11],
    'And Another': [12, 17]
  };
  var currentName = activeSheet.getName();
  if (! tabs[currentName]) { // not in the dictionary, abort
    return;
  }
  var cell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  if (tabs[currentName].indexOf(col) === -1) { // not in the dictionary, abort
    return;
  }
  if (cell.getFormula() !== "") {
    cell.copyTo(activeSheet.getRange(2, col, activeSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Both these answers seem to work. However, further to this, what if one tab starts on a different row. Is there a way to accommodate that also?

Comment: @StephenCousins I'd be happy to help, but can you clarify what you mean by "what if one tab starts on a different row?" and how the current solution fails?

Answer (score 1):

### You need to "bind" the column numbers to the tab names

- You can create two arrays - `tabs` and `columns`, whereby the order of the column numbers in `columns` should correspond to the one of the sheets in `tabs
- You check with `tabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName())` which to which array position the active sheet corresponds
- You get the column number corresponding to this array position, and thus to the present tab

```
function copyDown4() {
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var tabs = ['Imported','Another','And Another'];
var columns = [9,4,7];  //as example
if(tabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName()) !== -1){
  var column=columns[tabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName())];
  var cell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
    if(col==column){
      if(cell.getFormula() !== ""){
        var destination = activeSheet.getRange(2, col, activeSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
        cell.copyTo(destination)
      }
    }
  }
}
```